# Usage of "as if" as interjection

Tags: interjections

My question concerns the usage of *"as if"* as an idiomatic interjection. The references I have consulted (etymonline, online dictionaries, *etc.*) seem to agree that *"as if"* is used in this context to convey incredulity or doubt. This is how I have always thought of it.

The other day, I was with friends who used *"as if"* to express their surprise and joy about a wedding proposal. They weren't being sarcastic or incredulous; they were genuinely happy about the proposal. Here is a loosely paraphrased version of what they said:

*"As if they're getting married!"*

Is my friends' usage of *"as if"* standard? Is it a primarily regional distinction? (I am in Ontario, Canada right now.) The closest example we could come up with is someone says "I can't believe that you won first prize!" Of course, the person *can* and *does* believe it, so their words ought not to be taken literally. Is it the same idea with *"as if"*?

Comment: "As if they're getting married!" is ungrammatical because "as if" suggests an hypothetical proposition, which is normally casted in subjunctive: "As if they were getting married!".

Comment: Ooh, good point. That would make that usage nonstandard if they didn't use the subjunctive. Should I edit the paraphrase to make it correct, or is it better to leave it as is in order to convey what they were trying to say?

Comment: @Carlo_R.: That's not necessarily true. For example, I find "It looks as if they're going to get married" to be far superior to "It looks as if they were going to get married." (Though the latter does exist. I still remember being weirded out, when I read *Ethan Frome* some dozen years ago, by the characters saying things like "It looks as if it were going to rain.")

Comment: @d0sparky: You should definitely leave it as it is.

Comment: Is not "they're" a contraction of "they were"?

Comment: @Carlo_R., ungrammatical or not, the question is about usage.

Comment: Don't touch the question. It's excellent as it stands; and it's about the linguistic fact (or at least your best recollection of the fact), which should not be tampered with.

Comment: I've always heard it used as a negative remark, never as an expression of joy and surprise. It's probably a regionalism or a generational change in meaning. But whichever it is, it's not at all ungrammatical because (1) it's strictly an idiom, and they don't follow all the rules of grammar, and (2) the subjunctive is no longer considered a productive tense in English, according to linguists, so it'd be normal to say _As if they are getting married!_

Comment: @BillFranke: Well, usually when people talk about the demise of subjunctive *were*, they mean its replacement with *was*, as in "I wish I was [...]" (for "I wish I were [...]"). That's not really applicable here, since \*"they was" is nonstandard in all uses, irrealis or otherwise.

Comment: I entirely endorse StoneyB's comment: don't touch the question; maybe, as Bill Franke said, the subjuncitve is no longher considered a productive tense in English. And, however, "the question is about usage" JAM said.

Comment: @ruakh: Yes, one meaning is replacing _were_ with _was_ that way, but the other meaning is not using subjunctive forms except in set phrases: because it's dead, most of us don't know how to use it. Replacing _were_ with _are_ here would be a perfectly standard way of demonstrating that fact. It should be _As if they were getting married_ to be a subjunctive, but were you to ask the speaker to spell out _they're_ in the OP's sentence, they'd probably say _they are_ and certainly would never use _they was_.

Comment: @BillFranke: I think you're mistaken. When you say, "the other meaning is not using subjunctive forms except in set phrases", I believe your mistake is in the word "other": the *only* meaning is the replacement of *were* with *was*, except often in set phrases. (Well, when talking about *were*. There's also a present-subjunctive, and *its* death is when people replace *he be* with something like *he is* or *he should be*. But *were/are* alternation does not have to do with the death of the subjunctive.)

Comment: @Anixx: No, "they're" always means "they are", never "they were". For example, \*"When I talked to them yesterday, they're very angry" is ungrammatical.

Comment: @ruakh: Well, if you're going to make absolutist statements, then you'd better provide documentation to support them. You're not Noam Chomsky or John Lawler (neither am I, but I don't make such claims without support: there are plenty of commenters here do, though, & they seem to live in their own Little Prince-like world & hyperventilate on the excess helium in the atmosphere).

Comment: @BillFranke: I don't think I'm making "absolutist statements", but regardless, my claims are easily supported. If you read through pages [876](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&pg=PA876) through 878 of *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage*, you'll find that the "past subjunctive" examples are all about *were* vs. *was*, never *were* vs. *are*.

Comment: Confusion over this matter can be reduced by following the practice of Huddleston and Pullum and not referring to _were_ as subjunctive at all. Their term is ‘irrealis’ _were_. They argue that ‘there are no grounds for analysing this _were_ as a past tense counterpart of the _be_ that we find in constructions like _It’s vital that he be kind to her._

Comment: The older I get the less comfortable I am with imputing "meaning" to English inflectional forms as if they were Latin. I'd rather talk about "meaning" residing in the intention and eliciting the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OED’s only entry for the colloquial use of *as if* is ‘Without clause, as an exclamation. Typically used as a sardonic response to a stated or reported suggestion’. Like you, I have never heard it used in any other way. You say that *As if they're getting married!* is ‘a loosely paraphrased version of what they said’. Did they perhaps actually say something different? They could, for example, have meant that there was so much celebration of this good news that it was *as if they’re getting married **already***.

Comment: I apologize; that part of my question was poorly explained. The question was _"loosely paraphrased"_ in that I don't remember the exact wording. They may have said _"As if they're getting married"_ or _"As if they're engaged"_ or something to that effect. They didn't say anything that would have changed the meaning of the sentence, like *already*.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase *as if* is used extensively in the US, especially among the teenage and very young adult population.

It is used sarcastically, denying either the preceding statement or the statement that follows.

> James and Jodie dating? As if!
>
> As if I would ever go out with you.

The actual intent of the phrase is to convey *It is **not** as if X is happening.*

According to [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=as%20if) it means

> YEAH RIGHT! [but sarcastically]
> Made popular by the movie CLUELESS staring Alicia Silverstone.
> Meaning: I'm definetly not going to do that / not into that/ don't beleive that / etc.
> If a guy tells me he knows I'm in love with him (but I think he's a total loser), then I say to him "AS IF!"

In the US it would not be used in circumstances where the speaker agreed with or believed the associated statement.

Comment: This is my experience, too. However: 1) It doesn't really address what OP claims to have heard, or OP's question, and 2) You may want to take into account the qualification at the end of definition #4 [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=as+if) -- which is, to be sure, voted down, but not overwhelmingly.

Comment: @StoneyB I understand that OP may have heard a usage different from what I have described, but I have never heard such a usage in the US, Northeast or elsewhere. At least here, it is not standard.

Comment: FWIW I'm from the same jurisdiction as OP and I've never heard it either.

Answer (score 2):

I recently moved to Ottawa, Ontario from New Brunswick, Canada, and was extremely confused with the usage you described above. Everyone I talked to had "as if" meaning "I believe it, but am shocked or incredulous at the news".

You get news that X is going out with Y, a surprising but plausible scenario.
"As if X is going out with Y! Good for them!"

Whereas I did not have that meaning AT ALL. For me, "as if" has only one usage of "I completely do not believe the statement".

You get news that X is going out with Y, a completely impossible scenario that you do not believe for a second.
"As if X is dating Y! Stop spreading rumours."

My friends' usage was completely confusing to me.

I first encountered it in writing, and I was genuinely hurt because I thought the other person did not believe me. Later, when I spoke to him, he explained that he DID believe me, but he was just shocked at what I had said.

I did a quick poll, and the people back in New Brunswick that I asked only had the "doubt" definition and not the "surprised" definition. I have also been wondering if it's a regional expression. Where in Ontario are you seeing it?

Answer (score 1):

Only in the present tense, I imagine.

> Look at Mary in her white dress, staring at John while he puts that ring on her finger; as if they're getting married.